# PHP - REGEX validate class schedule

Tags: php, regex, validation

i have an input where in user will enter class schedule following this format

time days room
(11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF Room3)

i used this regex and it works

```
\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))-((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm])) (?=.{1})M{0,1}T{0,1}W{0,1}(TH){0,1}F{0,1}S{0,1}(SU){0,1} (?=.{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]*([-_.][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$
```

My problem now is how to allow user to input two or more schedule.
They can input two or more by separating each schedule by comma.

11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF Room3, 1:00 pm-2:30 pm TTH Room4

How can achieved this using also the regex above. thanks

Comment: Examples 1 and two don't meet your regex. You also can simplify the regex a bit with case insensitive and `\d`. e.g. `\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5]\d) ([ap]m))-((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5]\d) ([ap]m)) (?=.)M?T?W?(?:TH)?F?S?(?:SU)? (?=.)[a-z\d]*([-_.][a-z\d]*)?`

Comment: oh yeah my bad sorry @chris85. it works with the last example tho. But how about adding two or more schudule?

Comment: Two or more of the last format, or two or more of any of the three?

Comment: i'd probably go with the last format since its the one working. Like this 11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF Room3, 12:30 pm-1:30 pm TTH Room4

Comment: You should add that to the question. You might start by removing the closing anchor and using a word boundary. This regex is using a lot of capture groups though, do you need everything captured individually? I have to go now but i'll be back in a while if you dont have a response. Add everything to the question though so future readers can try to help with as little effort as needed.

Comment: Yup i need it individually because ill be exploding it later on. i already edited my question.

Comment: Do you want to extract information of each schedule like the first one? or you wanna just match them?

Comment: i wanna extract information too in the other schedule too.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/oQLwy9/1

Comment: @revo it only validates the first schedule.